# Do we need to add the adsbygoogle.js everytime?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I was looking at the source and noticed that there are three occurrences of the following code from adsense:

```
<script
        async
        src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Can I add this thing in the header once and be done with it? Will it help in speeding up my site?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It won't be the biggest boost though, because the browser would have it cached from the first load and would read it from disk. But you're right that it is redundant to have it in there three times, and it will get executed three times as well which will lead to incorrect data capture.

Best practice is technically to put it in the footer, or right before the closing body tag, so that it does not impact first paint. Everything in the `head` element should be stuff you need *before* initial page render - put everything else right before `</body>`.

Comment: ok. One more thing, does using cdnjs links instead of direct links for fontawesome and jquery javascripts result in speeding up the site?

Comment: Marginally, but first paint is what's most important to users, and moving a non-critical script to the footer can impact UX a lot more and make the site more _perceptibly_ fast. If you benefitted from my answers, toss me an upvote - if you have any additional questions or want some extra help, send me a DM.